# ipython notebook: missing toolbar labels

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have accidentally started a runaway process in ipython notebook, and I had to kill the ipython process. When I stared ipython notebook server again and connected with my browser, suddenly the toolbar labels are missing (see attached screenshot)

[image]

I have tried restarting my machine and starting ipython notebook anew, but this did not help.

Can somebody please advise how I can restore the toolbar labels?

Comment: Try re-installing Notebook.

Comment: @ChillarAnand - I have reinstalled `ipython-notebook`, but the problem still persists

Comment: Try clearing your ipython profile, maybe that got corrupted.

Comment: @simonzack clearing profile didn't help. What is the solution to this?